# Does SNS guarantee at least one message delivery to SQS?

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

From [SNS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/), i know there is a retry policy for SNS to SQS, but do they guarantee at least one message delivery to SQS?

Please give official quotes.

Comment: [Yes](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs:

> **Q: Does Amazon SNS provide at-least-once delivery of messages to Amazon SQS queues?**
>
> Amazon SNS is designed such that each message is delivered at least once to Amazon SQS standard queues.